# meglm in foreach loop keeps giving "factor-variable operators not allowed" error however meglm works perfectly outside foreach loop

Tags: foreach, macros, stata, stata-macros

I have a meglm statement with multiple binomial outcomes and I am trying to put it in a foreach loop but whenever I run this code, it gives me the error message "factor-variable operators not allowed":

```
foreach variable of varlist  burn_post2 {
       meglm `variable1' ib0.Active1_Sham0 || Participant:, family(binomial) link(logit) level(95) eform
}
```

However if I run this outside the foreach loop, it runs perfectly.

```
meglm burn_post2  ib0.Active1_Sham0 || Participant:, family(binomial) link(logit) level(95)
```

What could be going on? Is there anyway to overturn this error message?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your code. You wrote `` `variable1' `` where it should be `` `variable' ``.

```
foreach variable of varlist  burn_post2 {
       meglm `variable' ib0.Active1_Sham0 || Participant:, family(binomial) link(logit) level(95) eform
}
```